# How to use both tkinter and socket in python

Tags: python, windows, sockets, tkinter, python-3.10

By my project, I got into problem.
I made code without tkinter with socket. It worked really well,
then I added GUI to my code, and it shows me I used socket wrong.
Here's my code with GUI.

```
import socket as s
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog as d
t=Tk()
con=Text(t,font='Arail 12',state='disabled')
srcoll=Scrollbar(t,command=con.yview)
srcoll.pack(fill="y", side="right", anchor="e")
con.config(yscrollcommand = srcoll.set)
con.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
bb=Frame(t)
Joined=False
def recv():
  In=c.recv(2048)
  print(In.decode('utf-8'))
  t.after(50,recv)
def send():
    if messbar.get() != '' and Joined:
        ID=open('.\\Name.txt',encoding='utf-8').read()
        Out=ID+messbar.get()
        Out=Out.encode('utf-8')
        print(ID+' >'+messbar.get())
        messbar.delete('0',END)
        c.send(Out)
        
messbar=Entry(bb)
Button(bb,text='Send',command=lambda:send()).pack(side='right')
messbar.pack(side='right',fill='x',anchor='e')
messbar.bind('<Return>',lambda a:send())
bb.pack(fill='x',anchor='s')
t.title('△△△')
def print(text):
    con['state'] = 'normal'
    con.insert(END,text+'\n')
    con['state'] = 'disabled'
c=s.socket(s.AF_INET,s.SOCK_STREAM)
IPPort=d.askinteger('Port','Set your chat\'s port!')
print('Opened Server with Port: '+str(IPPort)+' IP: '+s.gethostbyname(s.gethostname()))
c.listen(5)
c,add=c.accept()
print(add,'joined.')
Joined=True
t.after(50,recv)
t.mainloop()
```

And this is what I've got for error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\△△△\△△△", line 38, in <module>
         c.listen(5)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

I have no idea why c.listen(5) cause OSError.

Comment: You need to call `c.bind(...)` before calling `c.listen(5)`.

Comment: Thank you for anwsering my question. I thought it will take like few months.